# SSRS - Trying to add a multi-select taxonomy as a parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, taxonomy

I'm creating an SSRS report that requires one parameter to be a multi-select taxonomy. What I'm hoping for is a dropdown that allows expansion into the desired area of nodes (to prevent it from getting prohibitively large).

Example of desired structure:

Fruit:

- Apple
- Banana

  - Yellow

    - Ripe
    - Not Ripe
  - Brown
- Orange

Example of non-desired structure:

Fruit:

Apple

Apple\Red

Apple\Red\Ripe

Apple\Red\Not Ripe

Banana

....Etc.

Is this possible? How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not possible with the current SSRS interface.

You can always build your own interface to collect the parameters and then hand the parameters to the report yourself, displaying the report in a ReportViewer control or streaming it to the client.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. Do you have a language recommendation for building the interface? I've only worked in SSRS so far but if building my own interface will allow me significantly greater functionality I'm very interested.

Comment: Since you need to use multi-value selections, you should look at using the ReportViewer component in a .NET web application or Windows program. Searching on SSRS, .NET, and reportviewer ( or combinations of those) should give plenty of results. Here's one: http://gotreportviewer.com/